# Json null reference exception ignoring try-catch block in debugger only, but catches fine in other contexts

Tags: c#, json, visual-studio, exception, visual-studio-debugging

Using the System.Text.Json library, I have a JsonNode from which I am extracting some data, which may or may not be null. For now, I have wrapped the code in a try-catch block instead of testing each element for being null, but I noticed some seemingly odd behaviour when one of the elements *was* null: the code would crash with a "NullReferenceException", despite that exception being included in the catch block (or when the catch block was set to handle Exception itself), but only when using the IDE (Visual Studio 2019)'s debugger.

Dummy code to reproduce the behaviour:

```
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Text.Json.Nodes;
...

string s = "{\"People\":[{\"Name\":\"Bob\",\"Age\":60},{\"Name\":\"Carl\",\"Age\":null}]}";
JsonNode n = JsonNode.Parse(s)["People"];
try { n[1]["Age"].ToJsonString(); } catch (Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show($"Caught Exception {ex.Message}"); }
```

If I run the debugger, the execution breaks with a `NullReferenceException` upon reaching that line.
If I do any of the following, the exception is successfully caught:

- run the debugger with the deprecated "Use Managed Compatability Mode" setting enabled
- execute the program outside of the IDE
- run the same code in the interactive console

While just testing for null works to avoid the issue in this case, I'd like to know what's going on for future reference in case it occurs in a more complicated situation.
Does anyone have an explanation as to what's causing the exception to not be caught in the debugging context, and whether there is a (non-deprecated) setting that can be changed (or other workaround/solution) to avoid the issue in future?

Comment: Can you give a sample JSON string that you used as input, and the code you used to parse it?

Comment: *If I run the debugger, the execution breaks* - This is most likely by design, so that you have a chance while debugging to inspect the exception details. It happens in other IDEs the same way, in my experience. Delphi/C++ Builder's IDE allows you to use conditional breakpoints to ignore specific exceptions like this when debugging, so that you can run through the exception handling code without the initial break happening.

Comment: @gunr2171 I updated the question with a code snippet that reproduces the behaviour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick note: When VS breaks during your exception, you can simply hit Run (or F5) to continue and the handler will be triggered as normal.

There are a number of Exceptions that are set to "break when thrown" while debugging in VS. There are a couple of ways to disable them.

1. In the exception popup, expand the little "Exception Settings" section in the dialog. It should give you options to disable "Break when this exception type is thrown".
2. You can bring up the full list in the [Exception Settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/sr-latn-rs/visualstudio/debugger/managing-exceptions-with-the-debugger?view=vs-2019) window: **Debug > Windows > Exception Settings**.
   Under "Common Language Runtime Exceptions" there should be a number of items ticked, including `System.NullReferenceException` in your system (unless you disabled it with the previous method). Feel free to un-tick the ones you don't want, or tick the ones you want VS to forcibly break on (to give you a chance to analyse the code when they're thrown).

Comment: Ah, I see; do you happen to know why some exceptions such as this one or `System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException` are ticked by default, while the vast majority are not, even the similar `System.Xaml.XamlParseException`?

Comment: I'm as in the dark as you are. Guess MS thinks that these exceptions deserve our attention more than others.